# What is the suitable H/W compatibility for av-1 encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, video-encoding, hardware-acceleration, transcode

Some videos are transcoded, h264 on ARM machine, h265 on Intel Skylake and av-1 on Intel RocketLake. File savings are better with av1 at the same quality but still at a high computational cost.

Avg computational cost in secs,

```
h264 => 14.77
h265 => 25.66
av1  => 85.00
```

No luck on wikipedia, what is the suitable H/W compatibility to encode in av1.

av1 encoder used, libaom-av1.

Comment: You already have compatible hardware. What is your actual question?

Comment: I think that the list in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AV1#Hardware) summarizes the subject well enough. AV1 hardware accelerated decoding becomes common, but hardware accelerated encoding it still exotic.

Comment: @Seth, H/W is compatible for decoding, I'm looking for "encoding".

Comment: @Rotem, Yeah, True. There is advancement in software driven solutions. I could see a major drift from libaom 2.x to 3.x on the same machine, but couldn't find a suitable processor in terms of Hardware. I have seen Netflix has rolled out av1 but only for its popular content. Can I assume that they even suffer in terms of H/W encoding ?

Comment: You still have compatible hardware. It can be done with any kind of hardware. If anything you are looking for an especially performant option but without going into detail about your targets it's going to be hard to say anything about it. In addition in most cases encoding is only done once so e.g. Netflix doesn't really have to care.

Comment: @Seth, Thanks for responding! A video which takes 80 secs(avg) to encode in av1 seem having a compatibility issue with the H/W. When the experiment is conducted on ARM machine, it was way worse. Here, I could say, Intel is more "better" than ARM, but unable to claim that Intel is the "compatible" machine due to its high encoding time. I understand av1 is lot more complex than x264 and x265, it takes more time to encode but I'm looking for a H/W which rightly fills the space. e.g I can claim x265 is "compatible" with skylake than ARM. Due to character limit, will continue in next comment.

Comment: This activity is regarding a Univ project, where there are many videos (100s) being uploaded, (which obviously requires transcoding) and needed to be served immediately. So, here the constraints are video needs to be served faster without much loss in quality (latency) & Optimal Univ B/W usage (file savings). I could see av1 is the right choice with the properties it hold. x265/x264 is the backup plan, but would like to stick to av1.

Comment: Now coming to Netflix, it could have performed av1 transcoding on all of its 4K library, but it didn't. My understanding is that they were trying to find a sweet spot bw encoding time (maintenance cost) vs video play hits, hence popular content.

Comment: My guess is that Netflix are using software, without any hardware accelerations. Wikipedia lists few products I never heard about, like "Allegro AL-E210
" and "Chips&Media WAVE627". I assume that only software solutions are relevant for your project (with todays technology). You may have to find your sweet spot between encoding time, hardware cost, maintenance/electricity cost, development effort, file savings...

Comment: @Rotem, hmm, sure. Thanks Rotem!